# How to update an Excel formula to just change the Row Value as I drag the formula down to the next consecutive row(s)

Tags: excel-formula

I have the following formula which calcs an If/Then statement:

```
=IF(J292="IN HEM",K2,IF(J292="HEMF1",K2,IF(J292="HEMF2",L2,IF(J292="HEMA",M2,IF(J292="STF",K11,IF(J292="STA",L11,IF(J292="LLF",K8,IF(J292="LLA",L8,IF(J292="BMTF",K6,IF(J292="BMTA",L6,IF(J292="NOF",K9,IF(J292="NOA",L9,IF(J292="ROF",K10,IF(J292="ROA",L10,IF(J292="OUTFAM",K3,IF(J292="OUTFPM",L3,IF(J292="OUTA",M3,IF(J292="(SELECT)",P2))))))))))))))))))
```

I would like to drag this formula down, changing only the row value (e.g., J292 becomes J293 throughout, and so forth as I drag down my worksheet).

What should I add to my formula to just change the Row and not the remaining formula?  At present I have to replace the Row # (Edit / Replace) to the next consecutive row and cut and past the new formula in.  This, of course, is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dollar sign (`$`) to lock the cell to a specified column or row.

If I understand you correctly, you want to lock `K2` so that it doesn't change to `K3`, `K4`, etc. as the formula is dragged down the worksheet.

To lock the formula to a certain row, write the dollar sign before the row value. So in this case, you would replace all occurrences of `K2` with `K$2`.

Likewise, to lock the formula to a certain column, write the dollar sign before the column value. For example, `$K2`.

You can also lock it to a specified cell by using dollar signs for both column and row, like `$K$2`.

You would repeat this for all rows that you don't want to change.